# passing normal items and array items to params function C#

Tags: c#, parameters, datarow

i want to add new row to table but by passing both normal variables and array variable like the example below

```
int value1=1;

int value2=2;

int[] numbers = new int[] {3, 4, 5};

DataTable1.Rows.Add(value1,value2,numbers)  // numbers as single items so the row will contain 5 values (1,2,3,4,5)
```

so should i build a new array and pass it ? or there a code spell to do that ?
thanks

Comment: Does building the new array work? Seems like that would be the way to go to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helper method will create a list from 1 to 5:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetItemsAndCollectionsAsItems<T>(params object[] itemsAndCollections)
{
    var result = new List<T>();
    foreach (var itemOrCollection in itemsAndCollections)
    {
        var collection = itemOrCollection as IEnumerable<T>;
        if (collection == null)
        {
            result.Add((T)itemOrCollection);
        }
        else
        {
            result.AddRange(collection);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And you call it this way:

```
int value1 = 1;
int value2 = 2;
int[] numbers = new int[] { 3, 4, 5 };

// Returns 1,2,3,4,5
IEnumerable<int> values = GetItemsAndCollectionsAsItems<int>(value1, value2, numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to be happen with this Int Array but yah, have a look on [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which stores data same as you want. Simply some tricky things have to do.